# Profile/Activity layout issue

Tags: bug, design

There seems to be an issue with the layout on the Activity tab in User Profile. The text and button at the bottom of the badge are obscured by the next row of tabs since the box is larger than normal when it holds a notification that a new badge has been awarded.

OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Version 1803
Browser: Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)
Browser Extensions: Google Docs Offline, Docs, Presentations, Tables

[image]

Comment: Could you edit the question to mention which browser and operating system you're using (including version numbers)? Also, if you have any extensions enabled, it would be useful to try to reproduce the issue without them.

Comment: On meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316061/ It's currently status-planned. This has been reproduced on a lot of different browsers and operating systems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [there's a duplicate on the network-wide meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316061/).